# Live search with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, search

I need to build a live search but i don't know much about ajax and javascript, but i understand html, css and php.Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
    function liveSearch(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="liveSearch(this.name)" name="searchWord"/>

<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'ezcart';
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Could not connect to the database: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $word = $_GET['q'];
    $sql= "SELECT prodNam FROM product WHERE prodNam LIKE '$q' ORDER BY prodNam ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div><p>".$row[prodNam]."</p></div>";
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Personally, I would use Jquery and the `$.get` or `$.post` function as they are meant exactly for this sort of thing and are much easier and (in my opinion) clearer.

Comment: I cant use jquery, this is for a unit's coursework.

Comment: you have `onkeypress="liveSearch(this.name)"`, which will send `searchWord`. I think you want `onkeypress="liveSearch(this.value)"` to send the value of the textbox.

Comment: are we to assume that your php code is in `getuser.php`? (1) your var is  `$word`->`$word = $_GET['q'];`, but you have `$q` in your query-> `LIKE '$q'`. (2) Also, you may want to add wildcards `%` to your query value -> `... LIKE '%$word%' ...`. (3) you should sanitize your user data -> `$word = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['q']);`

Comment: What is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the query

```
$word = $_GET['q'];

$sql= "SELECT prodNam FROM product WHERE prodNam LIKE '%".$word."%'";
```

For more information:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

first you need to generate a "onkeyup" event in your input to call your javascript function.

example:

```
 <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca alguna empresa" onkeyup="dinamic(this.value)" autocomplete="off"/>
```

here you will show the results

```
                <div class="resultados " >

                <table class="table hidden" id="resultados" name="resultados">




                </table>

    </div>
```

now lets write js function:

```
function dinamic(cadena) { //here cadena is your input value
var min = 3;
if (cadena.length >= min) { // true when the typed value have 3 or more characters
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  //method to pass the information to live_search.php
        url: 'live_search.php',
        data: 'cadena=' + cadena, //name of the post variable
        success: function (respuesta) { 
            $('#resultados').html(respuesta); //place to write results
        }
    });
}
if (cadena.length>min) { //will show or not the table depending on the input value
    document.getElementById('resultados').className = 'table';
} else
    document.getElementById('resultados').className += ' hidden';
```

}

lets go with the php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'ezcart';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Could not connect to the database: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

$word = $_POST['cadena'];
$sql= "SELECT prodNam FROM product WHERE prodNam LIKE '%".$word."%' ORDER BY prodNam ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div><p>".$row[prodNam]."</p></div>";
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

remember in my example your php file is called live_search.php

i recommend you tu use PDO instead of procedural php

if you want i can make an example with pdo.